# Need to find a proper Magento 2 Product Reviews extension

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'm currently working with a team of 5 members to build an e-commerce store, but I'm kinda struggling with choosing a great product reviews extension that is suitable for our site. Any suggestions for this kind of extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking for off-site content is off-topic on this site. Also, this is a programming Q&A site and this question is not about programming, so it is also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Real Review for Magento 2 extension provided by MageSolution. This comes with a lot of features, to name a few:
+ Empower admin to interact with customers thanks to the function of reply/comment on the review
+ Enable/Disable extension (on Disable mode, default review function is applied)
+ Configure the settings to allow review approval automatically.
+ With Real Review for Magento 2, only customers who have purchased a product can write a review for that product.

If you want to explore more, here is your solution: [Real Review for Magento 2](https://www.magesolution.com/real-review-for-magento-2.html)

Hope this will help!